# How to use functor which returns two value with standard library functions?

Tags: c++

I want to solve the following problem: I have a system of equations

```
   ax+by=c

   dx+ey=f
```

I have read in a tutorial that we can use a functor like the following

```
bool isIdd(int i){
 return ((i%2)==1)
}
```

and than we can use this functor with the find_if function.

I want to ask if it is possible two return two values from a functor (for example a tuple) and can we use it with find_if STL function?

Comment: A function can only ever return _one_ value (or none). This one value might be a kind of container for several other values like `tuple`, `vector`, etc. How should `find_if` interpret such a value? Can you make a small example what you expect to happen?

Comment: I want to find all coefficients of equations for which the solution is an integer.

Comment: The "like the following" is a regular function. You must have left something out or misunderstood something.

Comment: `std::find_if` expects a predicate with return type convertible to bool.

Comment: Your equation can be solved mathematically (line intersection).

Comment: Yes, a function can return a tuple. Yes, a tuple can be used in find_if. I don't know how this helps, but these are the answers on your questions

Comment: `find_if` works by finding an element from a container that satisfies a condition. I don't understand how you want to use it here.

Comment: `find_if` is no equation solver. I don't know if you read [the reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) or if just read the name and assumed what it might do. It finds an element in a range hat satisfies a condition. So you would need a container of _all_ possible solutions (or at least an iterator that iterates over all possible solutions). That's not how you solve equations in practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is possible to return two values from a functor (for example a tuple)

yes ,it is ,but you need also proper

```
operator bool()
```

As I understood, you want something like this:

```
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>

struct Pair{

    bool b;
    uint32_t data;

    operator bool()const{
        return this->b;
    }

    const Pair & isIdd(uint32_t p){
        if (p == this-> data) this->b = true;
     return *this ;
    }

    Pair(bool b , uint32_t data){
        this-> b = b;
        this->data = data;
    }

};

int main(){
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    Pair p(0,0);
    std::vector<uint32_t> vct {2};
    auto it = vct.begin ();
    auto b = std::bind(&Pair::isIdd,_1,_2);
    std::find_if(vct.begin (),vct.end (),b(p,*it++ ));
}
```

But what is here is not relevant to the task set as the solution of the equation.
If this fits to you and you really want to use `find_if` as this ,turn it into template and somehow store found data.